# Next.js 13 'TypeError: fetch failed' while trying to render static pages using getStaticProps. Need help fixing code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, sanity

I'm new to APIs. I'm using Sanity for my backend.

This is the error I get in the terminal:

```
- info Linting and checking validity of types
- info Creating an optimized production build
- info Compiled successfully
- info Collecting page data ..Using the Sanity client without specifying an API version is deprecated. See https://www.sanity.io/help/js-client-api-version
- info Collecting page data
[=   ] - info Generating static pages (2/3)Using the Sanity client without specifying an API version is deprecated. See https://www.sanity.io/help/js-client-api-version
[==  ] - info Generating static pages (2/3)
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11413:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async fetchPageInfo (C:\Users\ishaa\Documents\Github\my-portfolio\.next\server\pages\index.js:987:17)
    at async getStaticProps (C:\Users\ishaa\Documents\Github\my-portfolio\.next\server\pages\index.js:1142:22)
- info Generating static pages (3/3)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /
```

This is (one of) my API:

```
import { sanityClient } from "../../sanity";
import { PageInfo } from "../../typings";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import {groq} from "next-sanity";

const query = groq`
*[_type == "pageInfo"] [0]
`;

type Data = {
   pageInfo: PageInfo;
};

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<Data>
  ) {
    const pageInfo: PageInfo = await sanityClient.fetch(query);
    res.status(200).json({ pageInfo });
  }
```

This is my API fetch function (in /lib directory):

```
import { PageInfo } from "../typings";

export const fetchPageInfo = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/getPageInfo`);

  const data = await res.json();
  const pageInfo: PageInfo = data.pageInfo;
  
  return pageInfo;
};
```

This is my `getStaticProps` function in index.tsx:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<Props> = async () => {
  const pageInfo: PageInfo = await fetchPageInfo();
  const socials: Social[] = await fetchSocial();
  const experiences: Experience [] = await fetchExperiences();
  const skills: Skill[] = await fetchSkills();
  const projects: Project[] = await fetchProjects();

  return {
    props: {
      pageInfo,
      experiences,
      skills,
      projects,
      socials,
    },

    revalidate: 10,
  };
};
```

I was trying to follow along [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urgi2iz9P6U) on YouTube. I'm using `Next.js 13.4.12` (I use page router), `Sanity.io V3.14.4` and `node 18.16.0` (The video had Next.js 12.xx.xx).

After searching on the internet I tried a few fixes:

1. Changing `NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL="http://localhost:3000/"` to any other in `env.local` did not work.
2. adding the following to next.config.js did not work.

```
const dns = require("dns");
dns.setDefaultResultOrder("ipv4first")
```

3. A possible fix for this might be downgrading Next 13 to 12 or Node 17 or earlier, but I don't wish to do that (want to know how this works so I'm not stuck again in future).

What I understand after scavenging through [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props#using-getstaticprops-to-fetch-data-from-a-cms) is that I should not call an internal API route inside `getStaticProps`. Instead, I should be using API logic directly in `getStaticProps` (because API routes are not available during build-time, as the `localhost` server has not been started yet).

How can it be done?

Comment: Lol I got it! For anyone using Next.js 13 just use `getServerSideProps` Instead of `getStaticProps` and it will work!

Comment: I got stuck on the same problem, but I also can't fix it with getServerSideProps. Could you please share the code or details?